# MSI .NET 4.5 launch condition

Tags: windows-installer, .net-4.5, installshield

Based on this info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx I created a launch condition to save HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full "Release" into the variable `DOTNETVERSION4FULL` and then use it as a launch condition `>=378389`.

For some reason, the comparison failed even though 4.5 is installed. So I put [DOTNETVERSION4FULL] into the Message field, and it said the value was `#378389`. That's the right value, but what is that # doing there? Is it interfering with the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on description of the "Value" column in the [Registry Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OK, well that explains why it's there, so how to turn it back into a number so I can do the comparison?

Comment: Ah, I see, it can compare strings with > as well. That's handy.